# How to get year columnns to properly show up in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Here is what I am trying to get into a bar chart

```
Daysoutfromelection 2018    2020    2022
-48 1   0   0
-47 1   0   0
-46 6   0   0
-45 29  9   3
-44 55  26  3
-43 90  63  84
-42 120 77  250
-41 141 105 356
-40 163 185 422
-39 187 201 487
-38 193 204 487
-37 208 212 487
-36 238 229 644
-35 265 237 745
-34 286 272 802
-33 309 336 881
-32 335 518 951
-31 342 564 953
-30 356 585 953
-29 389 623 1150
-28 423 705 1264
-27 1374    3262    1771
-26 1698    5347    2225
-25 1974    8006    3818
-24 1986    10649   4896
-23 2006    11011   7313
-22 15285   36989   27733
-21 114431  142780  52288
-20 190945  209455  165335
-19 262430  407002  253878
-18 337650  603601  324661
-17 398354  652945  328549
-16 402512  717160  328748
-15 456827  859288  460281
-14 587248  1045476 594185
-13 737361  1228168 708165
-12 820264  1361718 804466
-11 888008  1482940 894919
-10 954156  1553120 949524
-9  960346  1613982 949552
-8  1016452 1742538 1042852
-7  1132337 1956437 1203929
-6  1234037 2116439 1350648
-5  1392544 2278454 1425982
-4  1487850 2390960 1499179
-3  1514435 2420439 1525419
-2  1514571 2420789 1549176
-1  1528274 2510411 1579877
0   1530403 2810924 1596362
1   1562526 2880302 1865700
2   1563402 2887366 1884284
3   1563403 2887572 1888305
4   1563405 2887579 1888305
5   1563405 2887579 1888308
```

Here is a picture in case you cannot see that properly

[image]

I am having major trouble getting all three columns to appear. I would like there to be 3 x values all next to eachother on a bar chart, with the y showcasing total votes so that you can compare which year had the most votes. I only have dplyr, ggplot2, tidyr, stringr, and tidyverse.

I've tried it like

```
viz2 <- data2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Daysoutfromelection, y = '2018'))+
  geom_bar()
  print(viz2)
```

But I have also switched around the x & y, tried using geom_line.
and also some other ways. Any help would be greatly appreciated in getting this data to properly appear

Answer (score 0):

You have to reshape your data first using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` so that your years become categories of a new column which I name `year` and the values go into a new column called `value`. Afterwards you could create your bar chart where (as you already have a `value` column) you have to use `geom_col`. Additionally I added a `position?"dodge"` to put the bars side by side:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

dat <- data2 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Daysoutfromelection, names_to = "year", values_to = "value")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Daysoutfromelection, y = value, fill = year)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

However, IMHO a line chart using `geom_line` is more appropriate for your data:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Daysoutfromelection, y = value, color = year)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]